# Download an Excel document from website with Powershell

Tags: powershell

recently I began to learn PowerShell to automate my job tasks.

So I want to access a web page and click on a button that download automatically an Excel file. This is the button that I want to click on:

```
<div class="NormalButton">

<a class="ActiveLink" title="Excel" alt="Excel" onclick="$find('ctl32').exportReport('EXCELOPENXML');" href="javascript:void(0)" style="padding:3px 8px 3px 8px;display:block;white-space:nowrap;text-decoration:none;">Excel</a>

</div>
```

This would be my PowerShell script:

```
$ie = New-Object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.Navigate("http://test.test/")
$ie.Visible = $true
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('a') | Where-Object {$_.onclick -eq "$find('ctl32').exportReport('EXCELOPENXML');"}
$link.click()
```

If I try to run it from the console I receive the error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."

If its useful I'm using PowerShell 4.0 and the webpage has a delay until the report is loaded.

Comment: Which expression is the error related to?

Comment: The error is releted to $link.click()

Comment: Does the path to the file change? If not invoke-webrequest might be just fine.

Comment: The path does not change, if I try it with Invoke-WebRequest it gives me that im Unauthorized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have completed it by the following code:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")


$url = "https://webpage.com"


$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application
$ie.navigate($url)
$ie.StatusBar = $false
$ie.ToolBar = $false
$ie.visible = $true



#Get Excel

Start-Sleep -s 40


$btnExcel = $ie.Document.links | where-object { $_.outerText -eq 'Excel' -and $_.innerText -eq 'Excel' }
$btnExcel.click()



# Get Internet Explorer Focus

Start-Sleep -s 5

[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("internet explorer")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{F6}");
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB}");
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait(" ");
Start-Sleep 1
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$file");
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{ENTER}");



# Get Internet Explorer Focus

Start-Sleep -s 1

[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("internet explorer")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("^{F4}");
```

Thank you all for you time :)

Answer (score 0):

I Think the Your problem is because you are using Double Quotes which powershell threat it like variable and Try to expand it, so try to change it to Single quote, from:

```
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('a') | Where-Object {$_.onclick -eq "$find('ctl32').exportReport('EXCELOPENXML');"}
```

to:

```
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('a') | Where-Object {$_.onclick -eq '$find('ctl32').exportReport('EXCELOPENXML');'}
```

Also, you can change the `-eq` to `-match` and take just a portion of it like:

```
$_.onclick -match '$find('ctl32').exportReport'
```

For more information see: [About Quoting Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6)

Comment: Still don't work, if I use Single Quote it gives me another error and if I use -match with double quotes still have the old issue

Comment: I mean `$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('a')` and then search manually for the `onclick` object and show the results, does it find anything?

Comment: Got it, it says that there is no method 'getElementByTagName'